# angular Carousel with 3 images

Tags: css, angularjs, carousel

I have multiple images, need to create a carousel which should shows 3 images at a time, the carousel should show the current active image in center and should also show the next image to right and previous image to left,please suggest a solution to do this  Thanks in advance.

I tried below one, but it shows only one image at a time

```
<ul rn-carousel rn-carousel-auto-slide rn-carousel-transition="slide" class="image">
                <li ng-repeat="image in slides">
                        <img class="alignLeft" ng-src="{{image}}"/>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Owl carousel supports multi image siders.
Please do have a look at http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/basic.html